# Why do I have to call a generic method as Class.<SomeType>func() insted of <SomeType>func() inside its own class?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> void func1(T t) { }

    public <T> void func2(T t) { }

    public void func3() {

        func2(0);
        this.<Integer>func2(0);
        // <Integer>func2(0); // error.

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        func1(0);
        Main.<Integer>func1(0);
        // <Integer>func1(0); // error.

    }
}
```

Error:

```
java: illegal start of expression
```

Why I'm getting an error inside both `func3` and `main` when trying to call a generic function as `<Integer>funcX(0)` even though all the functions are all inside the same class?

Comment: Because that's the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the specs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

This is the grammar for a method call:

```
MethodInvocation:
    MethodName ( ArgumentListopt )
    Primary . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
    super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
    ClassName . super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
    TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
```

Notice that none of them start with `NonWildTypeArguments` (the generics part). They all have an expression or `super` or `this` and a dot, followed by type arguments. I presume they thought it would be too hard to parse, especially when you have expressions like the following:

```
Is it
x < <Integer>genericMethod()
or is it
x << Integer > genericMethod() ?
```